# How to force all calls to pythons requests.get to use proxy by default?

Tags: python-requests, http-proxy

I am using a third party library in my code to get access token (ADAL). This library has a lot of calls to `requests.get` and `requests.post`. How can I force all the calls to use user provided proxies without having to modify each call to `requests.get('http://example.com', proxies=proxies`).

I cannot do export HTTP_PROXY. I have to do it from within my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could monkey patch requests.

At the very start of your script:

```python
import requests
import functools

orig_get = requests.get

proxies = { 
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}
requests.get = functools.partial(orig_get, proxies=proxies)
```